# How to stick app config settings to a staging slot via bicep

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-deployment-slots

How to stick app config settings to a slot via bicep?

Here is my bicep file:

```
var stagingSettings = [  
  {
    name: 'AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensions__durableTask__hubName'
    value: 'staging'
    slotSetting: true
  }
]


resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots@2018-11-01' = {
  name: name
  kind: kind
  location: location
  properties: {
    clientAffinityEnabled: true
    enabled: true
    httpsOnly: true
    serverFarmId: resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', servicePlanName)
    siteConfig: {
      use32BitWorkerProcess : false
      appSettings: stagingSettings 
    }
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
}
```

On deploying this code, I don't see app config settings stick to a slot:

[image]

checkbox is not checked. What am I missing?

Comment: did that work for you ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a [slotConfigNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/config-slotconfignames?tabs=bicep) resource:

> Names for connection strings, application settings, and external Azure storage account configuration
> identifiers to be marked as sticky to the deployment slot and not moved during a swap operation.
> This is valid for all deployment slots in an app.

Something like that should work:

```bicep
param functionAppName string

resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2018-11-01' existing = {
  name: functionAppName
}

resource functionApps 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2021-03-01' = {
  name: 'slotConfigNames'
  parent: functionApp
  properties: {
    // Sticky app settings
    appSettingNames: [
      'AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensions__durableTask__hubName'
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, how to have a setting stick to staging slot?

Comment: this should work, what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: When name is set to “ slotConfigNames”, resource type that is expected is “ Microsoft.Web/sites”, not “ Microsoft.Web/sites/slots” (at least with vscode). So it’s not possible to have a setting sticked to staging slot.

Comment: It works even for slots. It's a bit awkward/nonsense but works. ‍♂️

Comment: @BuckTheBug Can you point me to the documentation or an example where this is working for slots?

Comment: @PontiusTheBarbarian It's weird, it shouldn't work and I've figured it out by mistake - I set appsetting values for a slot and then I configure 'slotConfigNames' on the root application. The 'Deployment slot setting' flag is likely somehow inherited through the whole application. In my case, that is exactly what I need. If you had needed the flag somewhere checked and elsewhere unchecked, it wouldn't likely work.

Comment: @BuckTheBug and this is done via Bicep? Are you able to share an example?

Comment: @PontiusTheBarbarian Yeah, via Bicep. The same way that is used in the answer above. It means - I create a slot, set its AppSettings, and then I use slotConfigNames on the root App.

Answer (score 4):

## TL'DR

The [Microsoft.Web sites/config 'slotConfigNames'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/config-slotconfignames?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) resource has a `string array` property called `appSettingNames`. **ALL** slots' settings are scanned and matched against this array. Matches produce sticky settings.

### For example:

- Production slot settings: `{ DB: 'prod-db', FOO: 'bar' }`
- Staging slot settings: `{ DB: 'stg-db', BAZ: 'qux' }`
- SlotConfigNames: `[ 'DB', 'BAZ' ]`
- Result: `DB` **sticky** in `prod` and `stg` slots, `BAZ` **sticky** in `stg` slot

## Bicep sample

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-09-01' = {
  // omitted for breveity
}

var webAppProperties = {
  // omitted for brevity
}

// Deployed to the staging slot, and eventually swapped to the production slot, NOT STICKY!
var webAppSettings = {
  DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT: 'Demo'
}

var webAppStickySettings = {
  productionSlot: {
    DB: 'prod-db'
    FOO: 'bar'
  }
  stagingSlot: {
    DB: 'staging-db'
    BAZ: 'qux'
  }
}

// In this example: [ 'FOO', 'DB', 'BAZ' ]
var webAppStickySettingsKeys = [for setting in items(union(webAppStickySettings.productionSlot, webAppStickySettings.stagingSlot)): setting.key]

resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' = {
  // Production slot
  name: 'sample-webapp'
  location: location
  properties: webAppProperties
  resource appsettings 'config' = { name: 'appsettings', properties: webAppStickySettings.productionSlot /* Only prod slot sticky settings, other settings will arrive after staging slot swap */ }

  // Staging slot
  resource stagingSlot 'slots' = {
    name: 'staging'
    location: location
    properties: webAppProperties
    resource appsettings 'config' = { name: 'appsettings', properties: union(webAppSettings, webAppStickySettings.stagingSlot) }
  }

  // Sticky settings
  // Note: although this resource is a direct child of the webApp's production slot, this config applies to both the production and staging slots
  // This config simply matches the appSettingNames of the webApp's production slot AND staging slot
  // For all matches, it will mark the appSetting as sticky
  resource slotsettings 'config' = {
    name: 'slotConfigNames'
    properties: {
      appSettingNames: webAppStickySettingsKeys // in this example: [ 'FOO', 'DB', 'BAZ' ]
    }
  }
}
```

## Final Results

### Production Slot (Azure Web App Configuration Screenshot)

[image]

### Staging Slot (Azure Web App Configuration Screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

This is not currently possible via bicep for staging slots, only production slots. You can update config settings staging slots via [YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-app-service-settings-v1?view=azure-pipelines#examples), the portal or [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-appsettings-set).