# Stick setting to staging slot

Tags: azure-functions, azure-deployment, azure-deployment-slots

I have the following bicep file that adds deployment slots with config settings:

```
var appSettings = [
  {
    name: 'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE'
    value: 1    
  }
  {
    name: 'WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE'
    value: 1    
  }
]

var stagingSettings = [ 
  {
    name: 'AzureWebJobs.StarterFunction.Disabled'
    value: 1
  }
]

var productionSettings = [ 
  {
    name: 'AzureWebJobs.StarterFunction.Disabled'
    value: 0
  }
]

module functionAppTemplate 'functionApp.bicep' = {
  name: 'functionAppTemplate'
  params: {
    name: '${functionAppName}'
    kind: functionAppKind
    location: location
    servicePlanName: servicePlanName
    secretSettings: union(appSettings, productionSettings)
  }
  dependsOn: [
    servicePlanTemplate
  ]
}

module functionAppSlotTemplate 'functionAppSlot.bicep' = {
  name: 'functionAppSlotTemplate'
  params: {
    name: '${functionAppName}/staging'
    kind: functionAppKind
    location: location
    servicePlanName: servicePlanName
    secretSettings: union(appSettings, stagingSettings)
  }
  dependsOn: [
    functionAppTemplate
  ]
}
```

functionApp.bicep:

```
resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2018-02-01' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  kind: kind
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', servicePlanName)
    clientAffinityEnabled: false
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      use32BitWorkerProcess : false
      appSettings: secretSettings
    }
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
}


resource functionAppSlotConfig 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2021-03-01' = {
  name: 'slotConfigNames'
  parent: functionApp
  properties: {
    appSettingNames: [
      'AzureWebJobs.StarterFunction.Disabled'
    ]
  }
}
```

functionAppSlot.bicep

```
resource functionAppSlot 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots@2018-11-01' = {
  name: name
  kind: kind
  location: location
  properties: {
    clientAffinityEnabled: true
    enabled: true
    httpsOnly: true
    serverFarmId: resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', servicePlanName)
    siteConfig: {
      use32BitWorkerProcess : false
      appSettings: secretSettings
    }
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
}
```

I want this setting 'AzureWebJobs.StarterFunction.Disabled' only for staging slot (NOT for production slot) and stick that setting to staging slot. How would I update this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stick app config settings to a slot via bicep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71888548/how-to-stick-app-config-settings-to-a-slot-via-bicep)

Answer (score 3):

It is **not possible** to stick a setting to a staging slot using bicep. You will need to stick the setting to your production slot.

You will **need to use** `'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01'`

```
resource appServiceStickySetting 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
  name: 'slotConfigNames'
  parent: appService // <-- This needs to be a /sites resource (reference error below)
  properties: {
    appSettingNames: [
      "Setting Name Here"
    ]
  }
}
```

[Error You Get If You Enter For A Slot Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fud2J.png)

Answer (score -1):

For each of your application settings you can add

"slotSetting": true

This will only enable it for the slot in question

Comment: Can you please give an example with my code

Comment: just add that line for each setting you want slot specific
 {
    name: 'WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE'
    value: 1    ,
slotSetting: true
  }

Comment: Should I still use resource slotConfigNames

Comment: Can I remove this name: 'AzureWebJobs.StarterFunction.Disabled'
value: 0 from production?

Comment: @user989988 well it depends what you are trying to achieve

Comment: "slot in question": it's not possible for staging slots (using bicep at least). It expects Microsoft.Web/sites when using name: 'slotConfigNames'...

Comment: @MattDouhan Where is this documented? AppSettings property expects a key value pair so this would be invalid?